# How to fix the error "The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins."?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm building up a new application for hairStylers but the last update of Android Studio, version 3.4. I saw that was new codes to be applied and I did it, and after that, apper that error. i cannot continue building because it is on base grantle.

Base module gradle:

```
`apply plugin: 'com.android.instantapp'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    apply plugin: 'application'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.instantapp'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    apply plugin: 'application'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
}`
```

Comment: Can you add screen shot of the error log?

Comment: @AkinOkegbile If you're going to ask for logs, DO NOT ask for screenshots. That screws over OP rather than helping. Errors and code are expected to be available in text format on the site.

Comment: Please edit your post...it is quite confusing to read the build.gradle. Anyway, please remove `apply plugin: 'application'` from the `android` block.

Comment: @ecle sorry im bad at english, i did what you told me and now have a new a error that says: "This version of Android Studio cannot open this project, please retry with Android Studio 3.5 or newer."

Comment: @ArticWolf1720 Hmm, current stable Android Studio is 3.4; it seems that your project is using the unstable version